# node.js jade how to use style to limit the length of line of text

Tags: html, css, pug

With this code

```
      div.col-md-4    //#style({'word-wrap': 'break-word'}, {'width': 50px})
        h2
          a(href='/u/'+posts[j].user)=posts[j].user 
              !='says'
        p!='<small>' + posts[j].time

 + '</small>'
    p!= posts[j].post
```

I want to use this style

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word; width:50px;">
```

to limit length of one single line of text.
I've tried to put it after p! or after div, nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add attributes other than CSS classes and IDs with parentheses:

`div.some-class(align="center")`

So, to answer your question:

`div.col-md-4(style="word-wrap: break-word; width:50px;")`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
div.col-md-4(style="word-wrap: break-word; width:50px;")
```